# Can I test if website works well on iPhone/iPad/etc. without iPhone?

Tags: iphone

For various varieties of Windows and IEs virtual machines work perfectly. But how do I test against iPhones?

It's not iPhone-specific site, I just don't want it to be too broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a Mac you could install the iPhone SDK and use the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: Can I use it with 10.5 and without purchasing any dev keys? Apple dev website is as useless as ever (and 10.6 crashes my mac so I needed to downgrade back).

Comment: You need to register as an developer, but you do not need to pay anything. But for Leopard there used to be a download that is gone now, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should be ok by testing using Safari as that is the web browser that is available on both iPhone and iPad.

However, keep in mind the different amount of screen real estate for the iPhone and the reduced CPU power in both cases. These are not devices optimized to beat your quad-core Xeon base system but to reduce power consumption.

By testing against Safari (e.g. via Selenium RC and/or WebDriver) you can run a lot of tests without the device.

As a final confirmation before release I suggest to still borrow each of the target devices and run a test on it. Nothing beats the actual environment!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try [testiphone.com](http://www.testiphone.com)

Or install the iPhone SDK and use the iPhone Simulator if your using a Mac.

Comment: testiphone.com just points an iframe at the URL of your choice. It is not useful for testing how that URL will actually behave on an iPhone

Answer (score 1):

The iphone simulator doesn't have the restrictions like memory and processor.

But for web application, you could try [www.testiphone.com](http://www.testiphone.com/)

Comment: testiphone.com just points an iframe at the URL of your choice. It is not useful for testing how that URL will actually behave on an iPhone